# Can Chandalas perform Shraddhas and offer obesences to their ancestors ? Can they do Panchamahayajnas? (Only as per Smritis Puranas Tantras etc )

Tags: varnashrama, chandala

A Sudra is allowed to perform Paka Yajnas without Mantras. Medhatithi in his Manu Smriti commentary 10.41 says Mixed Castes are of the nature of Śūdras,’—i.e., having the character of the Śūdra, they are entitled to the rights and duties of that caste.

1)So can a Chandala also perform Panchamahayajnas without mantras ?

2)Do they perform Shraddha and honour their ancestors ?

3)Since Tantras are open to all and all can use Tantras can they perform Fire sacrifises too ?

Comment: Even comments are most welcome on this question

Comment: Shudras are allowed Paka Yajnas (including 5 maha yajna) and replace swaha/ Vasat with namah. They’re also allowed Shraaddha karma as it is because that has Swadha.

Comment: Yes @Archit but I want to know abt Chandalas

Comment: Yes okay I was actually clarifying Shudra point because the question said shudras can’t use mantras.